# AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

When I faced this problem, of course, I went to look at stackoverflow and looked for the problems, but then when new problems came and I did not understand why, I deleted and reinstalled python, but still the same problem (by the way, anaconda is installed on my computer) I run the selenium program in IDLE, then vscode and pycharm. i tried it, same problem

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
import random
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


url = "https://eksisozluk.com/mustafa-kemal-ataturk--34712?p="

pageCount = 1
entries = []
entryCount = 1

while pageCount <= 10:
    randomPage = random.randint(1,1290)
    newUrl = url + str(randomPage)
    webdriver.get(newUrl)

    elements = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'p.content')
    for element in elements:
        entries.append(element.text)
    time.sleep(3)
    pageCount += 1

with open("entries.txt","w",encoding = "UTF-8") as file:
    for entry in entries:
        file.write(str(entryCount) + ".\n" + entry + "\n")
        file.write("***********************************\n")
        entryCount += 1



driver.close()
```

Comment: get is only available on an instance like Chrome, Firefox of a webdriver, please see [this getting started link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 2):

You probably missed some steps

As you can see from the error there isn't any function about webdriver.get()

You should use

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox() # Write it before the loop.
```

And fix the function as well

```
while pageCount <= 10:
    randomPage = random.randint(1,1290)
    newUrl = url + str(randomPage)
    #webdriver.get(newUrl)
    driver.get(newUrl)
```

Comment: i have new error but i got this error before ,OSError: [WinError 216] This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher

Comment: What is selenium's version can you check that ?

Comment: probably is the new one bc i just started the selenium (Version: 4.9.0)

Comment: [Link for another similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74435728/i-cant-run-geckodriver-python-selenium-winerror-216)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=FirefoxService(GeckoDriverManager().install()))

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: p.content
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:182:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:394:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.sys.mjs:134:16

Comment: Did the browser open ?

Comment: turksun heralde ,turkce yaziyim firefox aciliyor sitede aciliyor ama ardindan idle da oyle bi hata aliyorum

Comment: yes I'm Turkish but probably it's aganist the rules to talk in Turkish

Comment: ok then do u understand the problem,

Comment: So probably     there is a problem with this line 
elements = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'p.content')

I would sugget you to try other elements

Comment: And I think you should check some tutorials as well because brute-forcing through the stackoverflow isn't the best teacher

Comment: i try it everything but no i coulndt the solve

Comment: elements = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'p.content')
What are you trying to get by using this line ?